# confusing javascript setinterval, loop and jquery ajax load priorities

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery

straight to the point
i have the following javascript and jquery code which update some checked rowsand do some stuff on each datatables row. here is my code:

```
function checkUpdate(){
setInterval(function(){
    var listLength = updateList.length;
    if(listLength > 0){
        for(var r=0; r<listLength; r++){
        //  console.log(r)
            var clID = updateList[r];
        //  console.log(clID)
            var rRow = $('#dataTable tbody tr').find('td[data-clientid="'+clID+'"]').parent('tr');
        //  console.log(rRow)
            var rRowIndex = rRow.index();
        //  console.log(rRowIndex)
            var rRowDataIndex = oTable.fnGetPosition(rRow[0]);
            console.log(rRowDataIndex)
            $.ajax({
                url: '/cgi-bin/if-Clients-list.jpl',
                data: 'session=' + recievedSession + '&clientid=' + clID + '&outputformat=json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(rowData){
        //          console.log(rowData)
                    var newRow = [];
                    var newOrderedRow = [];
            console.log(rRowDataIndex)
                    newRow.push(rRowDataIndex+1, "");
                    for (var title in rowData[0]){
                        newRow.push(rowData[0][title]);
                    }
            console.log(newRow)
                },

            });
        };
    }
},2000)
```

};

here is the problem:
after `$.ajax()` call, `rRowDataIndex` variable does not update or it updates but there is a problem in scopes and priorities that i couldn't understand
if i check 2 rows or more all the `console.log(newRow)`'s first elements will be the same
  can anyone help me?
**PS.** i can nor present any code on web
thanks every body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the AJAX call in a closure to capture the value of `rRowDataIndex` each time through the loop.

```
function checkUpdate() {
    setInterval(function () {
        var listLength = updateList.length;
        if (listLength > 0) {
            for (var r = 0; r < listLength; r++) {
                //  console.log(r)
                var clID = updateList[r];
                //  console.log(clID)
                var rRow = $('#dataTable tbody tr').find('td[data-clientid="' + clID + '"]').parent('tr');
                //  console.log(rRow)
                var rRowIndex = rRow.index();
                //  console.log(rRowIndex)
                var rRowDataIndex = oTable.fnGetPosition(rRow[0]);
                console.log(rRowDataIndex)
                (function (rRowDataIndex) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/cgi-bin/if-Clients-list.jpl',
                        data: 'session=' + recievedSession + '&clientid=' + clID + '&outputformat=json',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (rowData) {
                            //          console.log(rowData)
                            var newRow = [];
                            var newOrderedRow = [];
                            console.log(rRowDataIndex)
                            newRow.push(rRowDataIndex + 1, "");
                            for (var title in rowData[0]) {
                                newRow.push(rowData[0][title]);
                            }
                            console.log(newRow)
                        },

                    });
                })(rRowDataIndex);
            };
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: thanks so so so much it helped alot. wish i can add 10 useful votes